# Ordenar resultados com mês e ano

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

tenho uma tabela com os campos `mes E ano`. Como posso ordenar os resultados de acordo com o mês.

Já estou ordenando de acordo com o ano

**=> `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente' ORDER BY ano DESC`**
Agora como posso ordenar os meses também ?
 **Ex ( Janeiro, fev, mar... )**

PS: mes(varchar 255), ano (varchar 255) isso séria uma má pratica?

Comment: Como você esta armazenando o mês? Número ou escrito?

Comment: Escrito, isso seria uma má pratica?

Comment: Sim, por questão de desempenho, colocar um campo do tipo `tinyint` e número de 1 a 12, ficaria mais leve e mais simples de fazer a ordenação que você deseja

Comment: Má prática por usar o nome? Vai depender da regra da sua aplicação. Mas que usar `varchar 255` pra isso é absurdo, é.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade pode me indicar umas docs sobre esses valores? como usa-los corretamente?.

Comment: Em geral eu não consideraria ideal. O `VARCHAR 255` usando em utf8mb4 irá custar 1020 bytes, no máximo. Em versões antigas do MySQL, não sei atualmente, seria até necessário habilitar o `innodb_large_prefix` para que pudesse definir um index nessa situação. Enquanto que usar o `TINYINT` utiliza um único byte, portanto pode armazenar 256 valores, suficientes para armazenar `1` até `12`. O ano a mesma coisa, usando `SMALLINT` iria usar 2 bytes, e poderia definir "2017" tranquilamente.

Comment: Você não acha que utilizar um campo do tipo date seria mais conveniente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dessa forma com o mês do tipo **varchar**, tem que usar o **FIELD** no **ORDER BY**

```
SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente'
ORDER BY FIELD(mes, 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'), ano DESC
```

Comment: Obrigada Tafarel, funcionou corretamente!